# How to exclude context from raise exception in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

i want to throw error in function `postgresql`, but how if i want to exclude/remove the context from it errors?

what i try so far

```
RAISE 'messages error here (%) and here', NEW.request
      USING HINT = 'hint messages here';
```

i got return `message error`, `hint` and `context`..

> SQLSTATE[P0001]: Raise exception: 7 ERROR:  messages error here (var) and here\nHINT:  hint messages here\nCONTEXT:
> PL/pgSQL function approval_list_fnc_status() line 23 at RAISE (SQL:
> update "table" set "field1" = value1,
> "field2" = value2 where "id" =
> 9528ac4b-e20f-4be4-b251-42f0e28df9a9)"

how if i want to exclude the `context` from error?

Answer (score 3):

The context information is always there, but all the attributes of an error message (detail, hint, context, ...) are separate, and it is up to your client code to use only the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you can elide the context using

```
\set SHOW_CONTEXT never
```

Or if you also want to hide hints

```
\set VERBOSITY terse
```